# convert stroke to path

Tags: inkscape

my question probably falls into expected behaviour category, but i'd like to understand how to do it right.

im working on a design for [microfluidic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oas6Y.png) channels that needs to be an exact width of "channel" and "walls" (fill/stroke).
[image]

my limitation, i need the fill/channel to **always** stay the same width, no matter if i bend or whatever. ultimately i would like to draw a line, add stroke to that stroke/line(?) then be able to union it with other channels

TLDR; how do i create a shape like this, with exact inner channels?
[image]

maybe my wants are not in line 
1. with the SVG [spec](http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=1257)
2. Facilitate outset/inset by half stroke width - /inkscape/+bug/170898)

Comment: mybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEPd-gCW5m8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but the easiest way to create that shape is by building it with circles and lines first; then merge and stroke them:

[image: Lines and circles]

1. Draw circles and lines
2. Convert strokes to path (Path > Stroke to Path)

[image: Union body]

3. Select all elements and union them (Path > Union)

[image: Outline]

4. Give the path a stroke and set a white background

[image: Stroke order]

5. Change the stroke order to: *Stroke,Fill,Markers* to keep the channel width intact. (Fill and Stroke > Stroke style > Order) (As suggested by Socowi)

---

This approach also works for more complex shapes:

[image: Complex channel shape]

---

Another cool way of creating the channels is by creating the walls, and then use that as *shape* for a new path:

[image: Channel path]

1. First create two rectangles (the walls)
2. Union the rectangles (Path > Union)
3. Copy the shape (Ctrl+c)
4. Select the *Bezier curve and Straight line tool*
5. In the tool menu on top, select Shape: *From Clipboard*
6. Draw a path
7. Now you have a channel path that is still editable
8. Optional: convert this object to a path (Path > Object to path)

---

I hope this enables you to create the microfluidic channel design with Inkscape!

Comment: Note: Inkscape 0.92 is able to change the order in which fill and stroke are drawn. After uniting lines and circles, fill the shape white and draw the stroke *behind* the fill to ensure that the inner width of objects does not change.

Comment: ![](http://i.imgur.com/0asblRq.gifv)

first method is no go, it changes the wall width.

2nd thing looks intresting, ill check that kater and update.

thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer based on the good suggestion of Socowi. The first method now keeps the channel width intact.

Comment: a modified version works for me. but i'm having issues with a star shape. 
http://i.imgur.com/uG4jLL5.gifv

ill post later.