# Inkscape: Stroke to path on clipped object

Tags: inkscape, stroke, clipping-mask

1. Draw a circle with a wide stroke.
2. Draw a rectangle covering half.
3. Mark both.
4. Object > Clip > Set

How do I make convert the wide stroke of the resulting half circle to a path similar to: [convert stroke to path](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84562/convert-stroke-to-path)

[image: Half circle construction. How to get stroke as path?]

I have tried:

1. Mark clipped object
2. Path > Stroke to Path

But no result.

The circle serves as example. The goal is to be able to do this for any clipped object with wide strokes - not just circles.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the fill color from the resulted path, give a stroke color and make the stroke width narrow enough to leave some room. All this is available in the Fill & Stroke panel.

I think that using the object clip not necessarily is the best combining method. The clipping affects now to the converted circle and you see clipped open paths, not a closed path.

Convert the stroke of the circle to path at first, then intersect with a rectangle.

Here a rectangle and a converted circle are intersected. It's in the Path menu.

[image]

This is what you get, if you clip the circle at first and then convert it to a path.

[image]